# Notification.Builder add action

Tags: android, notifications, push, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to know which button is pressed so I do this on onReceive

```
Log.e(TAG, "Clicked " + extras.getInt("ACTION"));
```

and I always, no matter which button I press, get 3 `(ActionEnum.GO_TO_REMINDERS)` which is the `setContentIntent`.

another issue is that the notification is not closed unless I press on the notification buddy, but it's not closed when I press the button.

```
public void createNotification(Context context, Reminder reminder) {
    // Build notification
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(reminder.getDisplayString())
            .setContentText("Pick Action")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_remider)
            .setContentIntent(
                    getPendingAction(context, reminder,
                            ActionEnum.GO_TO_REMINDERS))
            .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Take",
                    getPendingAction(context, reminder, ActionEnum.TAKE))
            .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Snooze",
                    getPendingAction(context, reminder, ActionEnum.SNOOZE))
            .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Remove",
                    getPendingAction(context, reminder, ActionEnum.REMOVE))
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

}

public PendingIntent getPendingAction(Context context, Reminder reminder,
        ActionEnum action) {
    // Prepare intent which is triggered if the
    // notification is selected
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, RemindersReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("ID", reminder.getIntId());
    intent.putExtra("CLICK", true);
    intent.putExtra("ACTION", action.getValue());
    Log.e(TAG, "set action : " + action.getValue());

    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code in `getPendingAction()` will always return the same `PendingIntent`. You are not creating a separate `PendingIntent` each time you call this method. To ensure that each call creates a separate `PendingIntent`, you need to make the `Intent` unique. You can do this by setting the ACTION in the `Intent`, like this:

```
intent.setAction(action.name());
```

To ensure that any old `PendingIntent`s with the same ACTION are overwritten by the latest extras, I would also call `getBroadcast()` like this:

```
return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: A tiny tip to add: if you're working with multiple pending intents and things don't seem to work even after you have made changes like changing the flags, try restarting your debugging device, because Android may have cached the old pending intents.

Comment: Thank you this fixed my issue. Why do we need these magic methods like setAction that subtly break things if you don't use them ‍♂️just enforce it in the constructor or something,  and people can supply the same action if they want it to be re-used... so many minefields to walk through to get Android to work correctly.

Comment: The Android `Intent` system is very powerful, but also very complex. All frameworks have their faults. Just be happy you aren't coding for iOS ;-)